# PHPmailer multiple recipients error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have the following code with PHPmailer:

```
$tomailn[0] = 'imap2@gazler.com';
$tomailn[1] = 'imap@gazler.com';
foreach($tomailn as $value)
{
$mail->AddAddress($value, '');
}
```

But I am getting the error 'Could not instantiate mail function'.

If I remove an item from the array it works fine, but gives an error on when trying to add 2 or more addresses.  Any ideas why this is happening?  Is there a different way to add multiple e-mail addresses?

Cheers,
Gazler.

Comment: Can you post a link to the exact version of phpmailer you are using? There is not enough information here for anything than guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dig into the source code. Edit PHPMailer.php and find "`function MailSend`". (In 5.0.2, it's around line 564.)

In said function, remove the [@ error suppressor](http://php.net/@) from each call to `mail()`. Make sure [error_reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) is set to something reasonable for debugging. When developing, choose something like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

See if PHP shows any errors. PHPMailer only throws the instantiate exception when the last call to `mail()` returns something falsey, or if `$rt` never gets set, which would mean that `if ($this->Sender != '' && strlen(ini_get('safe_mode'))< 1)` evaluates to `true`.

Are you using safe mode? What do PHP Mailer `$mailer->Sender` and `ini_get('safe_mode')` say? (My guess: if you are not running in safe mode, but have it set to something like `Off`, this code would return `true`.)

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The fifth parameter is disabled in SAFE MODE in <b>/home/gazler/public_html/ahem/includes/php/class.phpmailer-lite.php</b> on line <b>590</b><br />
Could not instantiate mail function.
Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

Comment: As a result of the error, I removed the firth parameter and it mailed fine, the only issue is that it doesn't show all the recipients, although all do receive the e-mail.

Comment: Are you able to use PHPMailer's own SMTP transport? (I am not familiar enough with PHPMailer and safe_mode, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

did you try just `$mail->AddAddress($value);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times this error is caused when `from` header is not set or is invalid. Try setting this variable:

```
$mail->From = 'valid@mailaddress.com';
```

If it still doesn´t work, try one of the following:

- check if the `mail` is enabled in the server (and the `php.ini` settings);
- the **openssl** module is enabled (execute a `phpinfo()` and search for OpenSSL)

Comment: All three of these conditions are fine, I am sure the problem lies with the loop as an array with a single element works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked through the source code of PHPMailer, the message "Could not instantiate mail function" indicates that `mail()` returns false.

Can you try the same function, but with two different email-addresses that you know usually accepts emails?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading latest version of PHPMailer if you are not using one, it has bug fixes. Chances are that your mailer class has been messed with.

Answer (score 0):

'Could not instantiate mail function'.
Just check your mailer function working or not. many time this error cause due to limitation from hosting provider .many time Hosting provider block your mailing feature then usually you get this error